# Observable completed is not getting called when api returns 404, any alternate solutions when the api fails?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, httpclient

```
  onSave(payload) {
this.loading = true;
const addIdp = this.identityProviderService.save(payload);
this.autoUnsubscribe(addIdp.subscribe((data) => {
  this.notificationsService.success(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-success'), '');
  this.ref.close(data);
}, (error) => {
  this.notificationsService.error(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-error'), '');
}, () => {
  this.loading = false;
}));
```

}

identityProviderService.save call has httpClient in it

Comment: Where are you using finally here ?

Answer (score 2):

inside your error block check status of error:

```
(error) => {
    if (error.status === 404) {
        // custom code goes here
    }
  this.notificationsService.error(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-error'), '');
}
```

This should do the work !!!

Answer (score 1):

The observables by design do not trigger `complete` notification in case of an `error` notification. They are mutually exclusive, meaning if a stream errors out, it cannot `complete` or `next` thereafter. And if the stream completes, it cannot `error` or `next` thereafter.

So you either need to handle the error using `catchError` operator block or in the `error` callback block.

Try the following

```js
onSave(payload) {
  this.loading = true;
  const addIdp = this.identityProviderService.save(payload);
  this.autoUnsubscribe(addIdp.subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.loading = false;             // <-- set variable here
      this.notificationsService.success(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-success'), '');
      this.ref.close(data);
    }, 
    (error) => {
      this.loading = false;             // <-- and here
      this.notificationsService.error(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-error'), '');
    }
  );
}
```

Or you could use the [`finalize`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize) operator. From docs,

> [it] will call a specified function when the source terminates on
> complete or error.

```js
onSave(payload) {
  this.loading = true;
  const addIdp = this.identityProviderService.save(payload).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.loading = false)                   // <-- set variable here
  );
  this.autoUnsubscribe(addIdp.subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.notificationsService.success(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-success'), '');
      this.ref.close(data);
    }, 
    (error) => {
      this.notificationsService.error(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-error'), '');
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Indeed, do not confuse "completed" with a "finally". There is no "finally" with Observables.

Answer (score 0):

You should call finally before the subscribe, like so:

```js
addIdp
  .finally(() => this.loading = false) // <<-- Call it here
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.notificationsService.success(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-success'), '');
    this.ref.close(data);
  }, (error) => {
    this.notificationsService.error(this.translateService.instant('idp.form.add-error'), '');
  });
```

Comment: neither finally and finalize exists on the type Observable, This is what i am getting

Comment: `finally` is replaced with `finalize` in the newer versions of RxJS and it should be piped in using the `pipe()` function.